# Please help. Dashboard lights on after changing starter

Tags: engine, bmw, starter, dashboard-lights, 535i

I have a BMW 535i 2008. It won’t start so after diagnosing it I changed the starter but now after changing the starter all dashboards lights are on such as engine malfunctioning, transmission malfunction, ABS, etc. and now the stearing wheel is hard too. It started couple times but now I need to jump start my car.

Can anyone help.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Which exact codes are present?